# ireport - stacked measures in crossstab

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to create a crossstab with stacked measures but can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I basically want an output that looks like the below:

[image]

looks like this type of output can't be done using the crosstab wizard so I've tried manipulating the xml but still not getting this to work.....any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, either by creating new variables for variance and adding them to row groups or by creating new fields, calculating the variance values in the java/sql code and using them as row group values in the crosstab.